# Check if each cell in a table is equal to the cell above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How do you check in JS what the value of the td above the current one is in a table? I'm trying to get a table like this:

```
|column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | 
----------------------------------------
|        |         |         |         |
----------------------------------------
|        |         |  data   |         |
----------------------------------------
|        |         |  data   |   fox   |
----------------------------------------
|        |  bacon  |         |         |
----------------------------------------
|        |         |         |         |
```

To look like this:

```
|column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | 
----------------------------------------
|        |         |         |         |
----------------------------------------
|        |         |         |         |
--------------------  data   -----------
|        |         |         |   fox   |
----------------------------------------
|        |  bacon  |         |         |
----------------------------------------
|        |         |         |         |
```

My plan was to loop through each td element, to check the html of that td, then the one above, and if they are equal, hide the bottom one, and set the rowspan of the top one to 2.

I'm having trouble iterating through the td elements, I've tried some jQuery like this:

```
 $("#myTable td").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).html())
 });
```

But I can't access easily the cell above/below the current one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$("#myTable td").each(function(){
    var thisRowNum = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;

    var thisColNum = $(this).prevAll().length;

    var cellAbove = $(this)
        .closest('table')
        .find('tr:eq('+thisRowNum+') td:eq('+thisColNum+')'); // the cell

    var thisCell = $(this).html();
    if (thisCell !== "") {
        if ((thisCell === cellAbove.html())) {
            $(this).hide();
            cellAbove.attr("rowspan","2");
        }
    }

 });
```

Comment: Thanks very much, changed a couple of bits to make it work as needed - didn't need the -1 on the thisRowNum, and showed my method for hiding the cell and then setting the rowspan. Guess it should really check the existing rowspan value, and if it's not 0 then add one to existing value, but that can wait!

Comment: Oh, also, I'll pass the #myTable object to avoid the closest bit for every cell of the table.

Comment: Glad it helped. I see your fix re `index()` -- I'd forgotten the selector was for all tds, not just those in the current row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it, get the rows and cols and then create an array(a 2-D arraY of it and loop though it. It gives you much more flexibility. But I would say this job should be handled at the server side language you chose like JSP, ASP, PHP etc... that gives you much control.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a traversal algorithm yourself, storing the values from row to row.

```
var above = [];

$('#myTable tr').each(function()
{
  $(this).children('td').each(function(i)
  {
    if (above.length > i && $(above[i]).text() == $(this).text()) 
    {
      $(above[i]).attr('rowspan', ($(above[i]).attr('rowspan') || 1) + 1);
      $(this).remove();
    }
    else
    {
      above[i] = this;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it on an actual page, but in theory this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var container = ".mytable tbody > tr";
    var td_index, row_index = 0;

    $(container).each(function() {
        td_index = -1;
        row_index++;
        if(row_index > 0) {
            td_index ++;
            var above_tr = $(container+"eq("+(row_index-1)+")");
            var td_val = $(this).find("td:eq("+td_index+")").html();
            var above_td_val = $(above_tr).find("td:eq("+td_index+")").html();
            if(td_val == above_td_val) {
                $(above_tr).find("td:eq("+td_index+")").attr("rowspan", 2);
                $(this).find("td:eq("+td_index+")").remove();
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```